# Como y cuando puedo usar un do while? y como es su sintaxis

Tags: c#

Buenos dias a todos, estoy aprendiendo a programar y en el momento ya manejo mejor el ciclo for, pero respecto al do while quisiera entenderlo ya que he visto varios ejercicios que los resuelven con do, en vez de solo el while

Comment: Jorge, bienvenido las preguntas en StackOverflow no deben ser incompletas, por ejemplo debes colocar lo que has investigado o lo que has intentado, porque lo que buscas aquí es que te hagan el trabajo de investigar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do while es una estructura repetitiva, la cual ejecuta al menos una vez su bloque repetitivo, a diferencia del while o del for que podían no ejecutar el bloque.
Esta estructura repetitiva se utiliza cuando conocemos de antemano que por lo menos una vez se ejecutará el bloque repetitivo.

Ejemplo
En el ejemplo siguiente, las instrucciones del bucle do...while se ejecutan con la condición de que la variable i sea menor que 10.

```js
var s = "";

var i = 0;
do
{
    s +=  i + " ";
    i++;
} while (i < 10);

print (s);
// Output: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok Buen día el While se ocupa cuando quieras repetir un fragmento de código cero o muchas veces.
Por su parte Do While obliga al programa al ejecutar el fragmento de código por lo menos una 1 vez.

Supongamos un usuario va iniciar sesión en un sistema tuyo, y ocupas un **While** para mostrar el error cada vez que ingrese los datos incorrectos, pero cuando ingrese datos correctos no entrara en el bucle.
Por otro lado con **Do While** tendría que entrar por lo menos una vez en el bucle.

```
//Do While
do{
  //Operación a realizar por lo menos 1 vez
}while(condicion); //la condición se evalúa al ultimo

//While
//la condición se evalúa primero
while(condicion){
  //Operación a realizar 0 o más veces
}
```

Answer (score 2):

FOR: El bucle for ejecuta una instrucción o un bloque de instrucciones repetidamente hasta que una determinada expresión se evalúa como false. El bucle for es útil para recorrer en iteración matrices y para procesar secuencialmente.
Ejemplo
En el ejemplo siguiente el valor de int i se escribe en la consola y el valor de i se incrementa en 1 cada vez que se recorre el bucle.
C#

WHILE: La instrucción while ejecuta una instrucción o un bloque de instrucciones repetidamente hasta que una expresión especificada se evalúa como false.
En este ciclo el cuerpo de instrucciones se ejecuta mientras una condición permanezca como verdadera en el momento en que la condición se convierte en falsa el ciclo termina.

DO WHILE: Su diferencia básica con el ciclo while es que la prueba de condición es hecha al finalizar el ciclo, es decir las instrucciones se ejecutan cuando menos una vez porque primero ejecuta las instrucciones y al final evalúa la condición;
También se le conoce por esta razón como ciclo de condición de salida.

Ejemplo con DO WHILE

```
public class TestDoWhile 
{
    public static void Main () 
    {
        int x = 0;
        do 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            x++;
        } while (x < 5);
    }
}
/*
    Salida:
    0
    1
    2
    3
    4
*/
```

Ejemplo con WHILE

```
class WhileTest 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
        int n = 1;
        while (n < 6) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("El valor actual de n es {0}", n);
            n++;
        }
    }
}
/*
    Output:
    El valor actual de n es 1
    El valor actual de n es 2
    El valor actual de n es 3
    El valor actual de n es 4
    El valor actual de n es 5
 */
```

Alli todo dependera de tu contexto, espero te sirva. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

estructura básica del do-While:

```
do//en este bloque de código se pone lo que deseas hacer
{
//lo que quieras hacer
}
while(-condicion-);//mientras tu condición se cumpla, se seguirá realizando lo que se encuentre dentro del bloque do
```

Ejemplo:

```
do
{
Console.WriteLine(numero);
numero += 1;
}
while (numero "<" 20);
```

El código de ejemplo, imprimirá números hasta que la condición no se cumpla. (debería de terminar en 20, cuando la condición no se cumple, y saldría del do-while).
Cabe recalcar, que en esta estructura, el código que está en `do` **Siempre se ejecuta**, puesto que se evalúa al final lo que el código debe de realizar, por esto mismo, el ejemplo llega hasta el número 20, y no hasta el 19, donde en teoría debería parar.

También puede ser útil cuando no sabes que cantidad de veces se repetirá tu ciclo.

```
do
{
Console.WriteLine("Desea continuar? Si/No");
respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
}
while (respuesta != "No")
```

Como en este ejemplo, te preguntará si quieres continuar, hasta que tu le indiques que no, y es la principal diferencia respecto al for, `**do-While puede repetirse X veces que sea necesario.**`

Answer (score 2):

La diferencia del **do while** al **while** radica en que la condición dada se ejecuta por lo menos una vez, puesto que este valida al final si debe repetir el ciclo.

**Ejemplo simple**

**Con While** valida al inicio. Entrara al ciclo únicamente si el valor es igual a **no**.

```
char valor = 'si';

while(valor == 'no')
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mensaje prueba");
}
```

**Con DoWhile** valida al final. Entrara al ciclo una vez y repite el ciclo si el valor es igual a **no**.

```
char valor = 'si';

do
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mensaje prueba");
}
while(valor == 'no');
```